# Aptana 3.0.8 .exe Fail

Tags: javascript, installation, aptana

I'm trying to install Aptana 3.0.8 on my Windows Vista (I know...) 64-bit computer. When, I run the .exe, I get an error popup that says "Installer integrity check has failed. Common causes include incomplete download and damaged media. Contant the intaller's author to obtain a new copy." I know it's not an incomplete download, because I tried downloading the .exe again and got the same message. And I also tried installing it with Eclipse. I get "'Installing Software' has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed". So, I was hoping I could email the Aptana people directly about this, but I could only find a link to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this? https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Plugging+Studio+into+an+existing+Eclipse+configuration

The second error you got may be related to a network issue, so try again a few hours later.

In case you still have issues, you can open a ticket at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs

hope that helps a little.